# HTML Page is working but aspx page is not working on IIS

Tags: asp.net

IIS aspx website is not running if i include any aspx page but html page is working well and there are 2 more another application which is also aspx page that running very well.
 Please help

Comment: Please provide error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting an error message? Check the Application pool settings for the application that is not working and make sure they mirror those of the applications that are working.